# Lua given table A with metatable B, have functions in B defer to properties in A *before* identically-named properties in B

Tags: inheritance, lua, roblox, metatable, luau

So i'm making a system that runs through a list of "Tutorial Steps" during a tutorial, in sequence. the tutorial steps could be anything, but to guarantee some shared structure i've made an 'abstract' class TutorialStep. each unique type of tutorial step uses this as its metatable and __index, like this PressWASDStep for example:

**TutorialStep.lua**

```
local TutorialStepAbstract = {Name = "Tutorial Step"}
--setmetatable(TutorialStepAbstract, TutorialStepAbstract);
TutorialStepAbstract.isComplete = false;
function TutorialStepAbstract:new()
    local o = {};
    setmetatable(o, self);
    self.__index = self;
    --setmetatable(self, TutorialStepAbstract);
    return o
end
function TutorialStepAbstract:IsComplete()
    return self.isComplete;
end
function TutorialStepAbstract:Begin()
    print("beginning step: "..self.Name);
end
return TutorialStepAbstract;
```

**PressWASDStep.lua**

```
local TutorialStep = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.PPatrol_ReplicatedStorage.Tutorial.TutorialStep);
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService");
local HelperTChat = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.PPatrol_ReplicatedStorage.Modules.HelperTChat);

local Step = {}
--Step.__index = Step;
function Step:new()
    local o = TutorialStep:new();
    --setmetatable(o, self);
    --self.__index = self;
    o.Name = "Press WASD Step";
    o.isComplete = false;
    o.WPressed = false;
    o.APressed = false;
    o.SPressed = false;
    o.DPressed = false;
    return o;
end
--function Step:IsComplete()
--  return self.isComplete;
--end
function Step:Begin()
    task.spawn(function ()
        local messagedismisscallback = HelperTChat.ShowNewMessage("'You are currently at the patient's artery! Let’s start by going over how to move. Use the WASD keys to move.'", "nouserdimiss", "large");
        while not self.isComplete do
            self.WPressed = self.WPressed or UserInputService:IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.W);
            self.APressed = self.APressed or UserInputService:IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.A);
            self.SPressed = self.SPressed or UserInputService:IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.S);
            self.DPressed = self.DPressed or UserInputService:IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.D);

            if self.WPressed and self.APressed and self.SPressed and self.DPressed then
                self.isComplete = true;
                print("completing step "..self.Name);
                messagedismisscallback();
            end
            task.wait();
        end
    end, self)
end
return Step
```

the issue is, when i call `CurrentStep:IsComplete()`, it looks for the function in PressWASDStep, doesn't find it, and invokes the `IsComplete()` in TutorialStep, as it should. But the underlying property, `self.isComplete`, is always false here, because TutorialStep's `self.isComplete` and and PressWASDStep's `self.isComplete` are different variables.

I could get around this by referring to `isComplete` directly, but i'd rather figure out how to do this seemingly basic thing with lua, and i wouldn't be able to do anything else in `:IsComplete()` if i chose to later. I could also reimplement `:IsComplete()` in PressWASDStep, but then i'm losing the usefulness of a superclass/abstract class.

Is there a way to have the line `self.isComplete = true;` in PressWASDStep *modify the property of its metatable instead of defining/modifying a property of itself?* i'm not sure if that's the right way to phrase it, but essentially i want to have one shared property `isComplete` that is accessible to both TutorialStep and PressWASDStep.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is proper inheritance. Right now, when creating a `Step`, you actually create a `TutorialStep` instead. Sure, you then fill it with values but it's metatable and therefore it's "type" is a `TutorialStep`.

Instead you want it to be a `Step` (the commented-out code), and pass missing method calls to it's super.

This adapted (and not very beautiful) example "extends" TutorialStepAbstract.

```lua
local Step = setmetatable({ }, {__index = TutorialStep})

function Step:new()
    local o = TutorialStep:new()
    setmetatable(o, {__index = Step})
    ...
    return o
end
```

When you now call `IsComplete` it looks inside `Step`, doesn't find the method and continues in its `__index`. Notice the possibility of longer inheritance chains here. For every call, `self` stays the same, thus "sharing the property". You should extend on that to have explicit access to super so you can extend a method instead of just overwriting.

But please, just use a premade library and don't reinvent the wheel here :)
E.g.: https://github.com/Yonaba/30log

Comment: i'm pretty confused about how setmetatable and __index work then. could you elaborate on how that first line works? what's the difference between this and the code i have commented out?

Comment: The main difference is that you never made any kind of chaining. You assign a single metatable to an instance, so it can be either Step or TutorialStep. But for object oriented programming, it should be both. Therefore I give the instance a metatable pointing to Step, and Step has a metatable pointing to TutorialStep.

Comment: that makes sense to me conceptually! could you explain how it works on the syntax level?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what syntax is unclear, can you specify please? The first line assigns a metatable, with index pointing to the super class, to a new, empty table. The second setmetatable overwrites the metatable of o with a new metatable (uncached and unoptimized) pointing to the class.

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about the `__index` metamethod is that when you ask a table for a key that doesn't exist, it will then check for that key in the table assigned to the __index field.

That is why when you create an object with the `new` function, you create an essentially empty table and set the __index field. Since *every* field will be missing, the __index table effectively allows the empty table to behave like the original object. But, this isn't a true OOP constructor, it's [duck typing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

It sounds like you want to use the metatable as the equivalent to the super class, but that's not how it works. If you want a value to be accessible to the `self` object, it needs to be defined on the object itself, not its metatable.

So to have a unified set of properties from base class to child class, rather than try to set the __index method twice, try explicitly copying all the fields from the base class into a new table, then use that table as the starting point for your child class. This is composition, not inheritance, and is generally an easier pattern to read in your code.

```lua
local TutorialStepAbstract = {}

function TutorialStepAbstract:extend(additionalProps)
    local o = {
        Name = "Tutorial Step",
        isComplete = false,
    }
    -- rather than use the __index metatable, explicitly copy all of the fields onto the new object
    for k, v in pairs(self) do
        o[k] = v
    end

    -- add in any supplied fields
    for k, v in pairs(additionalProps) do
        o[k] = v
    end

    return o
end
```

```lua
local TutorialStep = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.PPatrol_ReplicatedStorage.Tutorial.TutorialStep)

local Step = {}
Step.__index = Step

function Step.new()
    -- initialize the Step by extending the Abstract, this will initialize the object with all the properties and methods of the base class
    local o = TutorialStep:extend({
        Name = "Press WASD Step",
        WPressed = false,
        APressed = false,
        SPressed = false,
        DPressed = false,
    })

    -- use traditional metatables for this class's members for simplicity sake
    setmetatable(o, Step)
    return o
end
```